# Creating a new Rect object or reusing an old one, i.e. changing parameters of an existing in terms of performance

Tags: java, rect

Lately, I've been working on my `Android` 2-D game engine and it utilizes a lot of `Rect` objects for drawing and re-drawing graphics. Every second, over a 1000 new `Rect` objects are needed. So, I can either create them in every cycle:

```
myRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
```

**OR** I could change the parameters of the old `Rect` objects (in other words, reuse them). In this case, the code would look like this:

```
myRect.left = newLeft;
myRect.top = newTop;
myRect.right = newRight;
myRect.bottom = newBottom;
```

Performance wise, which is more preferable, faster?

Comment: Give this a read https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/305590/java-game-preload-objects-and-reuse-vs-create-objects-at-runtime

Comment: @Matt - thank you, made things clearer to me